# How to make the following matrices?

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices

I follow the following code for the Matrices but it's not working so need some guidance to reproduce the code. I want to make the following Matrices (image)?
[image]

I follow the following code but it's not working. So give me some guidance to reproduce the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.1,0.3,0.5}

\DefineVerbatimEnvironment%
{MyVerbatim}{Verbatim}
{gobble=0,label=\hspace{.85\textwidth},labelposition=all,
 frame=single,framerule=3pt,framesep=5mm,rulecolor=\color{black}}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{6cm}
\begin{MyVerbatim}
JHENM KA  AG  KEW GENAH BHERKATEY HAN  (USER-U1_S1)
***   *** *** *** ***   ***       ***  (USER-U1_S1)
Words: 7 Correct: 0 Errors: 7 Percent correct = 0.00\% Error = 100.00\% Accuracy =  0.00\%
Insertions: 0 Deletions: 7 Substitutions: 0
JHENM KA  AG  KEW GENAH bherkatey han  (USER-U1_S2)
***   *** *** *** ***   bherkatey han  (USER-U1_S2)
Words: 7 Correct: 2 Errors: 5 Percent correct = 28.57\% Error = 71.43\% Accuracy = 28.57\%
Insertions: 0 Deletions: 5 Substitutions: 0
JHENM KA  AG  kew genah BHERKATEY HAN  (USER-U1_S3)
***   *** *** kew genah ***       ***  (USER-U1_S3)
Words: 7 Correct: 2 Errors: 5 Percent correct = 28.57\% Error = 71.43\% Accuracy = 28.57\%
Insertions: 0 Deletions: 5 Substitutions: 0
ABELAS ANESAN KA  deshemn hey  (USER-U2_S3)
***    ***    *** deshemn hey  (USER-U2_S3)
Words: 5 Correct: 2 Errors: 3 Percent correct = 40.00\% Error = 60.00\% Accuracy = 40.00\%
Insertions: 0 Deletions: 3 Substitutions: 0
abelas ANESAN KA  DESHEMN HEY  (USER-U2_S4)
abelas ***    *** ***     ***  (USER-U2_S4)
Words: 5 Correct: 1 Errors: 4 Percent correct = 20.00\% Error = 80.00\% Accuracy = 20.00\%
Insertions: 0 Deletions: 4 Substitutions: 0
TOTAL Words: 31 Correct: 7 Errors: 24
TOTAL Percent correct = 22.58\% Error = 77.42\% Accuracy = 22.58\%
TOTAL Insertions: 0 Deletions: 24 Substitutions: 0
\end{MyVerbatim}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(The precise values are to change according to your needs).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{color}


\textwidth14cm
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.1,0.3,0.5}

\DefineVerbatimEnvironment%
{MyVerbatim}{Verbatim}
{gobble=0,label=\hspace{.85\textwidth},labelposition=all,
 frame=single,framerule=3pt,framesep=5mm,rulecolor=\color{black}}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}
\begin{MyVerbatim}
JHENM KA  AG  KEW GENAH BHERKATEY HAN  (USER-U1_S1)
***   *** *** *** ***   ***       ***  (USER-U1_S1)
Words: 7 Correct: 0 Errors: 7 Percent correct = 0.00\% Error = 
100.00\% Accuracy =  0.00\%
Insertions: 0 Deletions: 7 Substitutions: 0
JHENM KA  AG  KEW GENAH bherkatey han  (USER-U1_S2)
***   *** *** *** ***   bherkatey han  (USER-U1_S2)
Words: 7 Correct: 2 Errors: 5 Percent correct = 28.57\% Error = 
71.43\% Accuracy = 28.57\%
Insertions: 0 Deletions: 5 Substitutions: 0
JHENM KA  AG  kew genah BHERKATEY HAN  (USER-U1_S3)
***   *** *** kew genah ***       ***  (USER-U1_S3)
Words: 7 Correct: 2 Errors: 5 Percent correct = 28.57\% Error =
 71.43\% Accuracy = 28.57\%
Insertions: 0 Deletions: 5 Substitutions: 0
ABELAS ANESAN KA  deshemn hey  (USER-U2_S3)
***    ***    *** deshemn hey  (USER-U2_S3)
Words: 5 Correct: 2 Errors: 3 Percent correct = 40.00\% Error = 
60.00\% Accuracy = 40.00\%
Insertions: 0 Deletions: 3 Substitutions: 0
abelas ANESAN KA  DESHEMN HEY  (USER-U2_S4)
abelas ***    *** ***     ***  (USER-U2_S4)
Words: 5 Correct: 1 Errors: 4 Percent correct = 20.00\% Error = 
80.00\% Accuracy = 20.00\%
Insertions: 0 Deletions: 4 Substitutions: 0
TOTAL Words: 31 Correct: 7 Errors: 24
TOTAL Percent correct = 22.58\% Error = 
77.42\% Accuracy = 22.58\%
TOTAL Insertions: 0 Deletions: 24 Substitutions: 0
\end{MyVerbatim}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\end{document}
```

[image]

And the version with rounded parentheses (Red ones. Green are from `fancyvrb`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{color}


\textwidth14cm
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.1,0.3,0.5}

\DefineVerbatimEnvironment%
{MyVerbatim}{Verbatim}
{gobble=0,label=\hspace{.85\textwidth},labelposition=all,
 frame=single,framerule=3pt,framesep=5mm,rulecolor=\color{green}}

\begin{document}
$\color{red}\left(\color{black}
\begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}
\begin{MyVerbatim}
JHENM KA  AG  KEW GENAH BHERKATEY HAN  (USER-U1_S1)
***   *** *** *** ***   ***       ***  (USER-U1_S1)
Words: 7 Correct: 0 Errors: 7 Percent correct = 0.00\% Error = 
100.00\% Accuracy =  0.00\%
Insertions: 0 Deletions: 7 Substitutions: 0
JHENM KA  AG  KEW GENAH bherkatey han  (USER-U1_S2)
***   *** *** *** ***   bherkatey han  (USER-U1_S2)
Words: 7 Correct: 2 Errors: 5 Percent correct = 28.57\% Error = 
71.43\% Accuracy = 28.57\%
Insertions: 0 Deletions: 5 Substitutions: 0
JHENM KA  AG  kew genah BHERKATEY HAN  (USER-U1_S3)
***   *** *** kew genah ***       ***  (USER-U1_S3)
Words: 7 Correct: 2 Errors: 5 Percent correct = 28.57\% Error =
 71.43\% Accuracy = 28.57\%
Insertions: 0 Deletions: 5 Substitutions: 0
ABELAS ANESAN KA  deshemn hey  (USER-U2_S3)
***    ***    *** deshemn hey  (USER-U2_S3)
Words: 5 Correct: 2 Errors: 3 Percent correct = 40.00\% Error = 
60.00\% Accuracy = 40.00\%
Insertions: 0 Deletions: 3 Substitutions: 0
abelas ANESAN KA  DESHEMN HEY  (USER-U2_S4)
abelas ***    *** ***     ***  (USER-U2_S4)
Words: 5 Correct: 1 Errors: 4 Percent correct = 20.00\% Error = 
80.00\% Accuracy = 20.00\%
Insertions: 0 Deletions: 4 Substitutions: 0
TOTAL Words: 31 Correct: 7 Errors: 24
TOTAL Percent correct = 22.58\% Error = 
77.42\% Accuracy = 22.58\%
TOTAL Insertions: 0 Deletions: 24 Substitutions: 0
\end{MyVerbatim}
\end{minipage}
\color{red}\right)$



\hfill



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it's possible to change the bracket style.

Comment: @LaTeXKhan If it was a question, please see the second version.

Comment: how i remove the just square brackets

Comment: @LaTeXKhan They a defined by the line `frame=single,framerule=3pt,framesep=5mm,rulecolor=\color{green}`, so you can remove it, leaving the final, second `}`.

Comment: How can i adjust the size of above matrix. I am interested to small the size of about matrix

Answer (score 3):

Another option with `tcolorbox` and its `listings` library. Of course, it needs to adjust brackets color and width.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.1,0.3,0.5}

\tikzset{myborderline/.style=%
        {rounded corners=7mm, line width=5pt, draw=green!80!black!40}
    }

\newtcblisting{myarray}{empty, notitle, arc=7mm, listing only,%  
    overlay unbroken = {%
        \draw[myborderline] ([xshift=8mm]frame.north west)%
             -| (frame.west) |- ([xshift=8mm]frame.south west);
        \draw[myborderline] ([xshift=-8mm]frame.north east)%
             -| (frame.east) |- ([xshift=-8mm]frame.south east);
    },
    listing options={language={}, basicstyle=\ttfamily\small, breaklines=true}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{myarray}
JHENM KA  AG  KEW GENAH BHERKATEY HAN  (USER-U1_S1)
***   *** *** *** ***   ***       ***  (USER-U1_S1)
Words: 7 Correct: 0 Errors: 7 Percent correct = 0.00% Error = 100.00% Accuracy =  0.00%
Insertions: 0 Deletions: 7 Substitutions: 0
JHENM KA  AG  KEW GENAH bherkatey han  (USER-U1_S2)
***   *** *** *** ***   bherkatey han  (USER-U1_S2)
Words: 7 Correct: 2 Errors: 5 Percent correct = 28.57% Error = 71.43% Accuracy = 28.57%
Insertions: 0 Deletions: 5 Substitutions: 0
JHENM KA  AG  kew genah BHERKATEY HAN  (USER-U1_S3)
***   *** *** kew genah ***       ***  (USER-U1_S3)
Words: 7 Correct: 2 Errors: 5 Percent correct = 28.57% Error = 71.43% Accuracy = 28.57%
Insertions: 0 Deletions: 5 Substitutions: 0
ABELAS ANESAN KA  deshemn hey  (USER-U2_S3)
***    ***    *** deshemn hey  (USER-U2_S3)
Words: 5 Correct: 2 Errors: 3 Percent correct = 40.00% Error = 60.00% Accuracy = 40.00%
Insertions: 0 Deletions: 3 Substitutions: 0
abelas ANESAN KA  DESHEMN HEY  (USER-U2_S4)
abelas ***    *** ***     ***  (USER-U2_S4)
Words: 5 Correct: 1 Errors: 4 Percent correct = 20.00% Error = 80.00% Accuracy = 20.00%
Insertions: 0 Deletions: 4 Substitutions: 0
TOTAL Words: 31 Correct: 7 Errors: 24
TOTAL Percent correct = 22.58% Error = 77.42% Accuracy = 22.58%
TOTAL Insertions: 0 Deletions: 24 Substitutions: 0
\end{myarray}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update** If you want to resize the figure it's possible to use `\resizebox` command (from `graphicx` package which is already loaded by `tcolorbox`). But because listings environments cannot be used as command argument an `lrbox` is needed (this last sentence and solution was taken from [David Carlisle answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110278/1952) to [resizebox fails for tikzpicture when used in conjunction with listing package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110275/resizebox-fails-for-tikzpicture-when-used-in-conjunction-with-listing-package)). Next code shows an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.1,0.3,0.5}

\tikzset{myborderline/.style=%
        {rounded corners=7mm, line width=5pt, draw=green!80!black!40}
    }

\newtcblisting{myarray}{empty, notitle, arc=7mm, listing only,%  
    overlay unbroken = {%
        \draw[myborderline] ([xshift=8mm]frame.north west)%
             -| (frame.west) |- ([xshift=8mm]frame.south west);
        \draw[myborderline] ([xshift=-8mm]frame.north east)%
             -| (frame.east) |- ([xshift=-8mm]frame.south east);
    },
    listing options={language={}, basicstyle=\ttfamily\small, breaklines=true}
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{lrbox}{0}%
\begin{myarray}
JHENM KA  AG  KEW GENAH BHERKATEY HAN  (USER-U1_S1)
***   *** *** *** ***   ***       ***  (USER-U1_S1)
Words: 7 Correct: 0 Errors: 7 Percent correct = 0.00% Error = 100.00% Accuracy =  0.00%
Insertions: 0 Deletions: 7 Substitutions: 0
JHENM KA  AG  KEW GENAH bherkatey han  (USER-U1_S2)
***   *** *** *** ***   bherkatey han  (USER-U1_S2)
Words: 7 Correct: 2 Errors: 5 Percent correct = 28.57% Error = 71.43% Accuracy = 28.57%
Insertions: 0 Deletions: 5 Substitutions: 0
JHENM KA  AG  kew genah BHERKATEY HAN  (USER-U1_S3)
***   *** *** kew genah ***       ***  (USER-U1_S3)
Words: 7 Correct: 2 Errors: 5 Percent correct = 28.57% Error = 71.43% Accuracy = 28.57%
Insertions: 0 Deletions: 5 Substitutions: 0
ABELAS ANESAN KA  deshemn hey  (USER-U2_S3)
***    ***    *** deshemn hey  (USER-U2_S3)
Words: 5 Correct: 2 Errors: 3 Percent correct = 40.00% Error = 60.00% Accuracy = 40.00%
Insertions: 0 Deletions: 3 Substitutions: 0
abelas ANESAN KA  DESHEMN HEY  (USER-U2_S4)
abelas ***    *** ***     ***  (USER-U2_S4)
Words: 5 Correct: 1 Errors: 4 Percent correct = 20.00% Error = 80.00% Accuracy = 20.00%
Insertions: 0 Deletions: 4 Substitutions: 0
TOTAL Words: 31 Correct: 7 Errors: 24
TOTAL Percent correct = 22.58% Error = 77.42% Accuracy = 22.58%
TOTAL Insertions: 0 Deletions: 24 Substitutions: 0
\end{myarray}%
\end{lrbox}

\begin{center}
\resizebox{.5\linewidth}{!}{\usebox0}
\end{center}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Now I'm interested to reduce the size of Matrix

Comment: @LaTeXKhan What does it means? If changing fontsize is enough, do it: `basicstyle=\ttfamily\tiny`. If you want to resaize the whole box could use `\resizebox`.

Comment: Yes I'm re-sizing the whole Matrix.

Comment: @LaTeXKhan I've added an example with `resizebox`